# Can there be a functional difference if I don't explicitly import React in a tsx file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

I've noticed that in my tsx files I don't have to add `import React from "react"` at the top of the file, even if I explicitly use types from React (e.g. `React.FC`).

I know that since React 17, it's not necessary anymore to always import React for jsx files. However, I would have still expected to need to do the import for TypeScript's sake when using for example `React.FC`. I couldn't find anything in the TypeScript docs stating that this would now be a sort of global.

I did notice that in vscode when I do add it, it doesn't mark it as unused (even if it may be redundant). So in the context of deciding whether I'll always add it or always leave it out in such cases, I'm wondering if there can be any functional difference or if it could cause a problem in the future.

```
import React from "react" // Needed ?

export const MyComponent: React.FC<MyProps> = (
  props
) => {
  return <div />
}
```